# ToolTip window help in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

How i can create pop-up window (with some text)when focus on TextInput (like in windows xp when i focus mouse cursor on file it shows short info).

ps: example of pop-up in windows xp [alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3884/2222ty.gif](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3884/2222ty.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of window you are referring to is generally refered to as a "Tooltip"

[I think that this is what you're looking for.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_3.html)